# Creating button and setting its value in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getDevicesButton").click(getContactList);
  //$("#getDeviceResourcesButton").click(getDeviceResources);
});

function onDeviceReady() {
  getContactList();
  getDeviceResources();
}

function getDeviceResources(value) {
  alert("getDeviceResources clicked, value passed " + value);
}

function getContactList() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.connector.mbed.com/endpoints/",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer <removed>"
    },
    cache: false,
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      debugger;
      alert(xhr.statusText);
      alert(thrownError);
    },
    success: function(json) {
      for (var i in json) {
        $('#deviceList').append('Device #' + (i) + ': <br/> name: ' + json[i].name + '<br/> type: ' + json[i].type + '<br/> <button id=getDeviceResourcesButton onclick=getDeviceResources(' + i + ')>Get Device Resources</button>');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h3>Device List</h3>
  <button id="getDevicesButton">Get Devices</button>
  <ul id="deviceList"></ul>
</body>
```

Inside a javascript function, I have a JSON result called json.
I iterate through it like this:

```
for (var i in json)
{
    $('#deviceList').append('Device #' +(i)+ ': <br/> name: ' + json[i].name + '<br/> type: ' + json[i].type + '<br/> <button id=getDeviceResourcesButton onclick=getDeviceResources('+i+')>Get Device Resources</button>');
}
```

currently getDeviceResources is defined as

```
function getDeviceResources(value)
{
    alert("getDeviceResources clicked, value passed "+value);
}
```

My problem - as it is, I get an alert w/ the expected value, but if I change `+i+` to `+json[i].name+` I don't even get an alert.

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: "Any idea what am I missing?" - An error message, likely, that is aborting your code before the alert can show. Check your console.

Comment: (1) Don't use `alert` for debugging, use `console.log` and the JavaScript debugger . See these [Chrome DevTools tips](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en) for more info. Other browsers have similar developer tools too. (2) No one can tell what's wrong from that code extract. Post a complete runnable example, either as a [Stack Overflow code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, added code.

Comment: Deleted the auth token so code won't work, and revoked it in the back end :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `json[i].name` as a string to the function. In case of `i`, its not throwing an error because its an integer. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/7ece9bq9/1/) is a fiddle to demonstrate the same.

```
function getDeviceResources(value)
{
    alert("getDeviceResources clicked, value passed "+value);
}
json = [
{name: "abc"},
{name: "bcd"}
];
console.log(json);
$(function(){
for (var i in json)
{
  $('#deviceList').append('Device #' +(i)+ ': <br/> name: ' + json[i].name + '<br/> type: ' + json[i].type + '<br/> <button id=getDeviceResourcesButton onclick=getDeviceResources("'+json[i].name+'")>Get Device Resources</button>');
  }
});
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something like that.. Thanks!